# PHP How to disable shipping methods based on subtotal

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I try to disable some shipping methods based on cart subtotal (after discounts).

```
// Disable Woocommerce shipping methods based on cart subtot

function wpsh_hide_shipping_based_on_subtotal( $rates, $package ) {
    // Retrieve cart subtotal
    //$cart_subtotal = $package['contents_cost'];
    $cart_subtotal = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total();
    
    // Shipping rate to be excluded
    $shipping_id1 = 'flat_rate:73';
    $shipping_id2 = 'flat_rate:75';
    $shipping_id3 = 'local_pickup:69';
    $shipping_id4 = 'flat_rate:76';
    $shipping_id5 = 'local_pickup:79';
 
    if ( $cart_subtotal < 99 ){
        unset( $rates[ $shipping_id4 ] ); 
        unset( $rates[ $shipping_id5 ] ); 
   }
    if ( $cart_subtotal >= 99 ){
        unset( $rates[ $shipping_id1 ] );   
        unset( $rates[ $shipping_id2 ] ); 
        unset( $rates[ $shipping_id3 ] );
   } 
        
    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'wpsh_hide_shipping_based_on_subtotal', 10, 2 );
```

This seems to work, but sometimes, especially with variable products it doesnt hide shipping methods below 99 subtotal. I dont have any clues why. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try with **woocommerce_shipping_packages** to hide the shipping method.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_packages', array( $this, 'hide_shipping_rates_from_packages'), 10, 1 );
    
public function hide_shipping_rates_from_packages( $packags ) {
    if ( !empty( WC()->cart ) ) {
        $cart_subtotal = wc_format_decimal( WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal( false ) ); // Without include compound taxes.
        if ( $cart_subtotal < 80 ) {
            foreach( $packags as $index => $package ) {
                unset($packags[$index]['rates']['free_shipping:1']);
            }
        }
     }
     return $packags;
}
```

For recurring carts, use the **woocommerce_package_rates** filter to hide shipping methods. This filter affects the session-stored package details and this filter is not triggered when rates are stored in the WC session data for this package.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', array( $this, 'hide_shipping_rates_from_package_rates'), 10, 2 );
public function hide_shipping_rates_from_package_rates( $package_rates, $package ) {
    if ( !empty( WC()->cart ) ) {
        $cart_subtotal = wc_format_decimal( WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal( false ) ); // Without include compound taxes.
        if ( $cart_subtotal < 80 ) {
            unset($packag_rates['free_shipping:1']);
        }
    }
    return $packag_rates;
}
```